# How to encode a file as synology vsmeta?

Tags: python, api, synology

I'm new to this site, so feel free to tell me if i forget any important information for this question.

I am using the VideoStation on a Synology NAS, which, until now, offered the possibility to get the metadata of a movie from TMDb or IMDb, which was then compiled into a .vsmeta file. Since this doesnt work anymore, I wanted to write a small python script, to generate this file, because I do not want to fill in the tables manually. I can get the actual Information via an IMDb API, but how can I convert these to Vsmeta? I found a library to encode the title, but does anyone know how to encode Cast, Rating, etc? Or is the non-human-readable part of the file unnecessary and I can just leave It out?